# Java network sniffer error issue

Tags: java, packet-sniffers

I am trying to write a packet sniffer in Java using an old tutorial I found online but having trouble debugging. I am getting an error stating my class pktSniffer is not inheriting an abstract method.

```
import jpcap.*;
import jpcap.packet.Packet;
import jpcap.PacketReceiver;

public class pktSniffer implements PacketReceiver {

public void handlePacket(Packet packet){

        System.out.println(packet);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException{

    NetworkInterface[] lists=jpcap.JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList();

    System.out.println("\n\t\t***Network Sniffer***\n");

    System.out.println("Found the following devices : ");

    for(NetworkInterface s: lists)
    {
        System.out.println("Name: " + s.name +" Description: " + s.description);
    }

    JpcapCaptor jpcap=JpcapCaptor.openDevice(JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList()[1],1000,false,20);
    jpcap.loopPacket(-1,new pktSniffer());

    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you have a look at jnetpcap (http://jnetpcap.com/) also, it's much more up to date than the old jpcap.

Answer (score 2):

> not inheriting an abstract method

Are you sure that the error wasn't that you are not *implementing* an abstact method?

According to:

- http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/javadoc/jpcap/PacketReceiver.html

and

- http://code.google.com/p/jdc-client/source/browse/trunk/JDC-Client+1.0/src/jpcap/PacketReceiver.java?r=8

your method should be called `receivePacket` instead of `handlePacket`

Comment: @Tom - I +1'ed a few of your answers in compensation ;-)

Comment: i changed the method name to receivePackets which seemed to have fixed the problem, but at run time i get an unsatisfied link error on this line of code: NetworkInterface[] lists = jpcap.JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList();